# How to move an object only by the Y-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now you can move an object only by local coordinates (only when you click on the object) up and down (Y). I need to make it so that I can move the object regardless of clicking, i.e. I can drive anywhere on the screen.

```
public float dragSpeed = 1f;
Vector3 lastMousePos;

void OnMouseDown( ) {
    lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
}

void OnMouseDrag() {
    Vector3 delta = Input.mousePosition - lastMousePos;
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.y += delta.y * dragSpeed;
    transform.position = pos;
    lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title somehow asks exactly the opposite of the question body ...

If I understand your question correctly you simply want to follow the mouse allways not just when holding the button down.

Simply do the movement in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) instead. And then use [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). You don't even need to store the mouse position and calculate the delta for this. `MoveTowards` already handles it for you.

Note that the entire code only makes sense if you actually want to move your objects in screen space **pixel** coordinates. E.g. if your object is within a Screespace Overlay Canvas. Otherwise you would probably want to convert the position to World-Space using

```
var worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + Vector3.forward * distanceToCamera);
```

Also note that currently your code is framerate dependent! You are moving the object with fixed speed of `dragSpeed Units / frame`. You rather would want to use a framerate independent value of `dragSpeed Units / real-time seconds`. Therefore you should use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) and adjust the `dragSpeed` value which now would need to be more or less `60` in order to get the same effect.

```
public float dragSpeed = 60f;

void Update() 
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Input.mousePosition, dragSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This now simply moves with a constant velocity towards the mouse position.